# Adjustments tag isn't displaying in {exp:store:checkout}

Tags: expresso-store

I'm trying to create a listing in my checkout tag of all the adjustments ( taxes, discount ).

However, when I use the {adjustments} tag, they don't print anything. The tags just show up with my markup. Am I missing something?

Below is a simplified version of my cart.

```
{exp:store:checkout next="cart/checkout"}
  {adjusments}
    <tr>
      <td>{adjustment:name}</td>
      <td>{adjustment:amount}</td>
    </tr>
  {/adjustments}
{/exp:store:checkout}
```

[image: Screen Capture of my cart]

Comment: https://exp-resso.com/docs/checkout_tag.html#adjustments_loop

Answer (score 1):

Ha! There was just a typo in the documentation. No wonder!

https://exp-resso.com/docs/checkout_tag.html#adjustments_loop

Comment: Nice catch. Will update our docs for the next version!